# how to nginx rewrite a.php,b.php,c.php to /index.php

Tags: php, nginx

Here is my rewrite code:

```
    location / {                 
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite "(*UTF8)^/(.*)$" / last;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {            
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "open_basedir=$document_root:/tmp/:/proc/";
    }
```

I wanna rewrite a.php,b.php,c.php to /index.php.but It doesn't work!but when I type a.,b.c.,Code above can work,I make some wrong?

Comment: Try `rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;`

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that any URI with a `.php` is processed by the PHP location block and therefore bypasses your rewrite rule. Use `try_files` in both your `/` location and your PHP location. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ { 
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "open_basedir=$document_root:/tmp/:/proc/";
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.